# Accessing Outlook mails of Different Account in C#.Net

Tags: c#, api, outlook

I want to access outlook mails but b-with different account.
I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop libraries. I was able to read mails only from my computer or  from where the exe is running. I want to create one service which will read mails from account which is provided no matter on which machine I am running my exe.

Comment: Have you ever red [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#UseaclientlibrarytoaccesstheMailAPI)?

Answer (score 0):

If you deal only with Exchange mailboxes you may consider using EWS, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Also you may find [Office 365 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/platform-development-overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) helpful.

In general, I'd suggest using the System.Net namespace classes to connect to any mailbox.